# Determining when a sql server schedule will trigger within a time span?

Tags: sql-server, scheduling

In a system I manage there are several SQL Server Agent jobs that run based off schedules defined within dbo.sysschedules.

I would like to create a calendar view on my application that will display when each of these jobs would be scheduled to run in given time span.  For example, if I have schedule that's set to run on the first and fourth Monday of the month at 8:00 AM, then given the timespan of the current month (4/2013) I would like to get the dates "4/1/2013 8:00AM, 4/22/2013 8:00AM" back.

Has anyone come across a method for accomplishing this? I know that I could read in the schedule definition and figure this out pragmatically, but I was curious whether anyone has already come up with the solution before I get into the weeds myself.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no buit-in functionality that does what you want. Unless you can find something on the web, rolling up your sleeves and wading into the horror that is sysSchedules may be your only option.

Answer (score 1):

These links look like they will get you on the right path...

[Generate SQL Agent Job Schedule](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1622/generate-sql-agent-job-schedule-report/)

[Accessing SQL Server Agent Data](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1244/accessing-sql-server-agent-data/)

Here is a solution I altered from mssqltips.com.

```
    WITH next_run_time AS
    (       
    SELECT      sJOBSCH.schedule_id AS  [ScheduleID]            
                ,[sJOB].[name] AS [JobName]
                ,CASE 
                WHEN [sJOBH].[run_date] IS NULL OR [sJOBH].[run_time] IS NULL THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(
                CAST([sJOBH].[run_date] AS CHAR(8))
                + ' ' 
                + STUFF(
                STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBH].[run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                    , 3, 0, ':')
                , 6, 0, ':')
                AS DATETIME)
                END AS [LastRunDateTime]
                , CASE [sJOBSCH].[NextRunDate]
                WHEN 0 THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(
                CAST([sJOBSCH].[NextRunDate] AS CHAR(8))
                + ' ' 
                + STUFF(
                    STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBSCH].[NextRunTime] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                    , 3, 0, ':')
                , 6, 0, ':')
                AS DATETIME)
                END AS [NextRunDateTime]
    FROM        [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sJOB]
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT      [job_id]
                ,schedule_id
                ,MIN([next_run_date]) AS [NextRunDate]
                ,MIN([next_run_time]) AS [NextRunTime]
    FROM        [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules]
    GROUP BY    [job_id],schedule_id
    )       AS [sJOBSCH]

    ON      [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBSCH].[job_id]
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT      [job_id]
                ,[run_date]
                ,[run_time]
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [job_id] ORDER BY [run_date] DESC, [run_time] DESC

    )           AS RowNumber

    FROM        [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory]
    WHERE       [step_id] = 0
    )       AS  [sJOBH]

        ON      [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBH].[job_id]
    AND         [sJOBH].[RowNumber] = 1
    )

    , Occurrence AS
    (
    SELECT      schedule_id AS [ScheduleID]
                ,[schedule_uid] AS [ScheduleUID]
                ,[name] AS [ScheduleName]
                ,CASE [enabled]
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
                WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
                END AS [IsEnabled]
                ,CASE 
                WHEN [freq_type] = 64 THEN 'Start automatically when SQL Server Agent starts'
                WHEN [freq_type] = 128 THEN 'Start whenever the CPUs become idle'
                WHEN [freq_type] IN (4,8,16,32) THEN 'Recurring'
                WHEN [freq_type] = 1 THEN 'One Time'
                END [ScheduleType]
                ,CASE [freq_type]
                WHEN 1 THEN 'One Time'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Daily'
                WHEN 8 THEN 'Weekly'
                WHEN 16 THEN 'Monthly'
                WHEN 32 THEN 'Monthly - Relative to Frequency Interval'
                WHEN 64 THEN 'Start automatically when SQL Server Agent starts'
                WHEN 128 THEN 'Start whenever the CPUs become idle'
                END [Occurrence]
                ,CASE [freq_type]
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Occurs every ' + CAST([freq_interval] AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' day(s)'
                WHEN 8 THEN 'Occurs every ' + CAST([freq_recurrence_factor] AS VARCHAR(3)) 
                        + ' week(s) on '
                        + CASE WHEN [freq_interval] & 1 = 1 THEN 'Sunday' ELSE '' END
                        + CASE WHEN [freq_interval] & 2 = 2 THEN ', Monday' ELSE '' END
                        + CASE WHEN [freq_interval] & 4 = 4 THEN ', Tuesday' ELSE '' END
                        + CASE WHEN [freq_interval] & 8 = 8 THEN ', Wednesday' ELSE '' END
                        + CASE WHEN [freq_interval] & 16 = 16 THEN ', Thursday' ELSE '' END
                        + CASE WHEN [freq_interval] & 32 = 32 THEN ', Friday' ELSE '' END
                        + CASE WHEN [freq_interval] & 64 = 64 THEN ', Saturday' ELSE '' END
                WHEN 16 THEN 'Occurs on Day ' + CAST([freq_interval] AS VARCHAR(3)) 
                             + ' of every '
                             + CAST([freq_recurrence_factor] AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' month(s)'
                WHEN 32 THEN 'Occurs on '
                         + CASE [freq_relative_interval]
                            WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'Second'
                            WHEN 4 THEN 'Third'
                            WHEN 8 THEN 'Fourth'
                            WHEN 16 THEN 'Last'
                           END
                         + ' ' 
                         + CASE [freq_interval]
                            WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
                            WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
                            WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
                            WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
                            WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
                            WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
                            WHEN 8 THEN 'Day'
                            WHEN 9 THEN 'Weekday'
                            WHEN 10 THEN 'Weekend day'
                           END
                         + ' of every ' + CAST([freq_recurrence_factor] AS VARCHAR(3)) 
                         + ' month(s)'
                END AS [Recurrence]
                ,CASE [freq_subday_type]
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Occurs once at ' 
                        + STUFF(
                     STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([active_start_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
                                    , 3, 0, ':')
                                , 6, 0, ':')
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Occurs every ' 
                        + CAST([freq_subday_interval] AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' Second(s) between ' 
                        + STUFF(
                       STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([active_start_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
                                    , 3, 0, ':')
                                , 6, 0, ':')
                        + ' & ' 
                        + STUFF(
                        STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([active_end_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
                                    , 3, 0, ':')
                                , 6, 0, ':')
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Occurs every ' 
                        + CAST([freq_subday_interval] AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' Minute(s) between ' 
                        + STUFF(
                       STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([active_start_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
                                    , 3, 0, ':')
                                , 6, 0, ':')
                        + ' & ' 
                        + STUFF(
                        STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([active_end_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
                                    , 3, 0, ':')
                                , 6, 0, ':')
                WHEN 8 THEN 'Occurs every ' 
                        + CAST([freq_subday_interval] AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' Hour(s) between ' 
                        + STUFF(
                        STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([active_start_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
                                    , 3, 0, ':')
                                , 6, 0, ':')
                        + ' & ' 
                        + STUFF(
                        STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([active_end_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
                                    , 3, 0, ':')
                                , 6, 0, ':')
                END [Frequency]
                ,STUFF(
                    STUFF(CAST([active_start_date] AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 0, '-')
                        , 8, 0, '-') AS [ScheduleUsageStartDate]
                ,STUFF(
                STUFF(CAST([active_end_date] AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 0, '-')
                    , 8, 0, '-') AS [ScheduleUsageEndDate]
                ,[date_created] AS [ScheduleCreatedOn]
                ,[date_modified] AS [ScheduleLastModifiedOn]
    FROM        [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules]

    )

    Select      nrt.JobName,nrt.LastRunDateTime,nrt.NextRunDateTime
                ,o.Occurrence,o.Recurrence
    From        next_run_time AS nrt
    Inner Join  Occurrence o
        ON      nrt.ScheduleID = o.ScheduleID
```

And the results from this query for me.

JobName===========syspolicy_purge_history

LastRunDateTime====4/23/13 19:47

NextRunDateTime====4/24/13 2:00

Occurrence=========Daily

Recurrence=========Occurs every 1 day(s)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this tool and run Profiler to look at the queries its executing. Its a handy tool.

http://sqlsoft.co.uk/sqljobvis.php

Comment: This is only showing the runs that have already occurred. I am more interested in figuring out when runs will happen in the future, beyond just the next run.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following in MSDB database:

```
select sj.name, sch.next_run_date, sch.next_run_time 
from sysjobschedules sch
inner join sysjobs sj
    on sj.job_id = sch.job_id
```

Comment: This will get me the immediate next run for a schedule but I am more interested in when a schedule will be set to run in the a given time range.

Comment: Take a look at the sysschedules table it has the info you need but will take a bit of work to work what you want.